# Finding the number of integers $(x_1,...,x_k)$ such that $1\leq x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_k\leq n$

Tags: combinatorics

I got this problem:

> Find the number of vectors in the set $S=\{(x_1,...,x_k)\in \Bbb{Z}^k| 1\leq x_i \leq n \land x_1<x_2<...<x_k\}$ where $1\leq k,n\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $k>n$ it is clear that there are no elements in $S$. Assume therefore that $k\le n$. Now the numbers $(x_1,...,x_k)$ are just a subset of $(1,2,...,n)$, and the condition $x_1<x_2<...<x_k$ ensures that we don't need to worry about ordering. The number of elements in $S$ is then the number of ways of selecting $k$ objects from a collection of $n$ objects, which is simply $n\choose k$.

Comment: Thanks for the sentence "the condition $x_1<x_2<...<x_k$ ensures that we don't need to worry about ordering". Now I got it.

Comment: "We don't need to worry about ordering" - Does it mean that after we select $k$ numbers from $n$, there is only one way to put them in the desired order?